# getDeclaredMethods() return inherited methods if superclass is default

Tags: java, generics

I have two classes

```java
// BaseClass.java
class BaseClass<T> {
 
   public String getTest(){
       return "one";
   }
 
   public String getTest2(T t){
       return "two";
   }
   public String getTest3(T t){
       return "three";
   }
}
 
// OverrideClass.java
public class OverrideClass extends BaseClass<Test>{
}
```

I tried to run the following code

```java
// Test.java
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Class<OverrideClass> overrideClass = OverrideClass.class;
       Method[] declaredMethods = overrideClass.getDeclaredMethods();
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(declaredMethods));
   }
}
```

and I think it should output

```java
[]
```

but in fact the output is

```java
[public java.lang.String OverrideClass.getTest()]
```

Through the bytecode, I thought this a bridge method, but I don't know why it generates, and if I make BaseClass public it will disappear.

```java
  // access flags 0x1041
  public synthetic bridge getTest()Ljava/lang/String;
   L0
    LINENUMBER 1 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL BaseClass.getTest ()Ljava/lang/String;
    ARETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this LOverrideClass; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1
}
```

My question is:

1. Why `getTest()` generate a bridge method if BaseClass is default?
2. Why `getTest2()` and `getTest3()` did not generate their bridge method? This seems to be related to generics.

Comment: I get all 3 of the `getTest` methods. Are you sure that you did not miss anything when describing your situation?

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: @Sweeper I sure, I get all 3 of  ```getTest```method only if is no generic

Comment: @Lino My Java version is 1.8.0_281

Comment: @Lino Though I see the same thing on Java 18.0.1

Comment: @Slaw That's really weird. I'm on Java 17 and cannot reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: @Sweeper That's even weirder then. I still see the behavior if I compile with `--release 17`. I don't have a JDK 17 installed though, so I can't test with that right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have analyzed the issue and here is the results. I have simplified a bit the example from the question.

This answer handles the first question of OP

> Why getTest() generate a bridge method if BaseClass is default?

For second question regarding the inconsistency appearing with generics you can read [Denis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72354692/7237884)

### Example 1

```
class BaseClass {

    public String getTest(){
        return "one";
    }

    public String getTest2(){
        return "two";
    }
    public String getTest3(){
        return "three";
    }
}


public class OverrideClass extends BaseClass{}


public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<OverrideClass> overrideClass1 = OverrideClass.class;
    Method[] declaredMethods1 = overrideClass1.getDeclaredMethods();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(declaredMethods1));
   }
}
```

The execution of this either with JDK 8 or with JDK 17 has always the same result

```
[public java.lang.String OverrideClass.getTest(), public java.lang.String OverrideClass.getTest2(), public java.lang.String OverrideClass.getTest3()]
```

### Example 2

Just modify the above example into

```
public class BaseClass {

    public String getTest(){
        return "one";
    }

    public String getTest2(){
        return "two";
    }
    public String getTest3(){
        return "three";
    }
}
```

Note that the change is in the access modifier on Base class which now is **public**!

The execution of this produces the expected behavior of  `[]`

This however is not a bug of JDK. It is intended to be this way.

### Explanation

The reason that in the example1 the `getDeclaredMethods()` has returned the same methods of the parent class is not because those methods are printed as inherited. It is because those are bridge methods that actually belong to that child class (OverrideClass).

This functionality has been added long ago and the explanation as you can see [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-6342411) from developers of oracle was

> The proposal is to add bridge methods in these very rare cases to fix
> a problem in reflection with no other forseen fix or workaround.
> Specifically, we would generate a bridge method when a public method
> is inherited from a nonpublic class into a public class.

And as you can also see [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6815786), the most recent comment from oracle developers was

> The bridge methods are added in a case like this where a public class
> public methods from a non-public superclass to allow for the
> possibility of reflective access of the subclasses methods
> JDK-6342411).
>
> Closing this issue as not a bug.

So this is happening only in non public parent classes because in this case the public methods that are inherited need to be added as bridge methods in that children class.

In the **example 2** where bridge methods do not exist, if you try to print out the disassembled code using `javap -c OverrideClass` you will see the following

```
public class OverrideClass extends BaseClass {
      public OverrideClass();
        Code:
           0: aload_0
           1: invokespecial #1                  // Method BaseClass."<init>":()V
           4: return
    }
```

In the **example 1** with bridge methods existing, if you try to print out the disassembled code using `javap -c OverrideClass` you will see the following

```
public class OverrideClass extends BaseClass {
  public OverrideClass();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method BaseClass."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public java.lang.String getTest3();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #7                  // Method BaseClass.getTest3:()Ljava/lang/String;
       4: areturn

  public java.lang.String getTest2();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #11                 // Method BaseClass.getTest2:()Ljava/lang/String;
       4: areturn

  public java.lang.String getTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #14                 // Method BaseClass.getTest:()Ljava/lang/String;
       4: areturn
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. > **Why getTest() generate a bridge method if BaseClass is default?**

   See [Panagiotis Bougioukos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72345557/6486622).
2. > **Why getTest2() and getTest3() did not generate their bridge method? this seems to be related to generics.**

   This is a bug, from description of [JDK-8216196. No visibility bridges are created for generic methods](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8216196):

   > javac is normally adding visibility bridges for methods if they are public but declared by a package-private class:

   > This is not the case if a method has a generic type:

The bug is fixed by [JDK-8203488. Remove error generation from TransTypes](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8203488), backported to 11.0.1

#### Example, run results

```java
package org.example;

class BaseClass<T> {

    public String getTest() {
        return "one";
    }

    public String getTest2(T t) {
        return "two";
    }

    public String getTest3(T t) {
        return "three";
    }
}
```

```java
package org.example;

public class OverrideClass extends BaseClass<Void> {
}
```

```java
package org.example.other; // Note other package

import org.example.OverrideClass;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class OverrideClass2 extends OverrideClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Arrays.stream(OverrideClass.class.getDeclaredMethods())
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        invokeGetTestReflectively();
        System.out.println("invoked 'getTest' reflectively");
        invokeGetTest2Reflectively();
        System.out.println("invoked 'getTest2' reflectively");
    }

    private static void invokeGetTestReflectively() throws Exception {
        Method method = OverrideClass2.class.getMethod("getTest");
        method.invoke(new OverrideClass2());
    }

    private static void invokeGetTest2Reflectively() throws Exception {
        Method method = OverrideClass2.class.getMethod("getTest2", Object.class);
        method.invoke(new OverrideClass2(), new Object[]{null});
    }
}
```

##### Run results

###### Java 8, openjdk version "1.8.0_332"

```
public java.lang.String org.example.OverrideClass.getTest()
invoked 'getTest' reflectively
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.example.other.OverrideClass2 can not access a member of class org.example.BaseClass with modifiers "public"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:296)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:288)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at org.example.other.OverrideClass2.invokeGetTest2Reflectively(OverrideClass2.java:26)
    at org.example.other.OverrideClass2.main(OverrideClass2.java:15)
```

- The reflective access is allowed but there is a bug in javac

###### Java 17, openjdk version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19 LTS

```
public java.lang.String org.example.OverrideClass.getTest()
public java.lang.String org.example.OverrideClass.getTest2(java.lang.Object)
public java.lang.String org.example.OverrideClass.getTest3(java.lang.Object)
invoked 'getTest' reflectively
invoked 'getTest2' reflectively
```

- Reflective access allowed, no bug in javac

Comment: the part 1 has already been answered previously in my posted answer again with same referenced links and same quotes from Oracle developers. It would be good to add additional value to the thread like the part 2 of your answer which is a valid case of what OP asked about generics.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos, referred to your answer in the first part instead, left the second part as is

Comment: also referred to your answer about the generics issue which is very good covered in your answer. Upvoted also the answer both for content and for keeping the thread as good as possible for OP to read easily